# Replacing Font Awesome Social Media Icons With Images

Tags: html, css, icons, social-media

I've attempted to replace fa icons on blogger with custom icons using

```
.fa-facebook{content:url("")}
```

The images work on Chrome but not FF or IE. 
What's going on/Is there a workaround?

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hd3nc4e3/)

[image: Google Chrome]

[image: Firefox]

Comment: post your demo code in jsfiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hd3nc4e3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [W3school](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp):

> Definition and Usage
>
> The content property is used with the :before and :after
>   pseudo-elements, to insert generated content.

So instead of `.fa-facebook{content:url("")}` use `.fa-facebook:before{content:url("")}`

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/hd3nc4e3/3/)

Answer (score 2):

According to the official rules, the `content` property only works for `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements. So in this case, Chrome breaks the rules!

Solution: add `::before` to the selectors for the icons, then it will work in all browsers.

```css
.fa-facebook::before {
  content: url("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-VPr8buUo47w/VjMsRPIzr-I/AAAAAAAAAL4/AYBtvlNCQiw/s64-Ic42/clouds_social_media_icons_set_64x64_0000_facebook.png");
}
.fa-twitter::before {
  content: url("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-yDH1FuHcQ5s/VjMsQ2lXvxI/AAAAAAAAAMg/i8JHsTh6aU8/s64-Ic42/clouds_social_media_icons_set_64x64_0002_twitter.png");
}
.fa-instagram::before {
  content: url("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-VIveL13ocQc/VjMw7JU6dGI/AAAAAAAAAOo/AGxBey6rtC0/s64-Ic42/clouds_social_media_icons_set_64x64_0001_instagram.png")
}
.fa-pinterest::before {
  content: url("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-Or5qfrW2PFI/VjMsQziUH5I/AAAAAAAAAL8/bOIkRNtMSbo/s64-Ic42/clouds_social_media_icons_set_64x64_0001_pinterest.png");
}
.fa-google-plus::before {
  content: url("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-xIroPQ5PdBk/VjMsRhd-1VI/AAAAAAAAAMM/rcruNIarpPU/s64-Ic42/clouds_social_media_icons_set_64x64_0003_google%25252B.png");
}
.fa-heart::before {
  content: url("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-ymc-N9bHkpo/VjNAMkaZnpI/AAAAAAAAAPY/Yv1qLXXuG7E/s64-Ic42/clouds_social_media_icons_set_64x64_0001_bloglovin.png");
}
```

```html
<ul class="site-social-networks secondary-2-primary style-default show-title">
  <li><a href="#" class="facebook" target="_blank" title="Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>Facebook</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="twitter" target="_blank" title="Twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>Twitter</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="instagram" target="_blank" title="Instagram"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>Instagram</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="pinterest" target="_blank" title="Pinterest"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i>Pinterest</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="bloglovin" target="_blank" title="Bloglovin"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i>Bloglovin</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="googleplus" target="_blank" title="Google Plus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>Google Plus</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use image in background instead of content for e.g

```
.fa-facebook{
    content: '';
    background:url("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-VPr8buUo47w/VjMsRPIzr-I/AAAAAAAAAL4/AYBtvlNCQiw/s64-Ic42/clouds_social_media_icons_set_64x64_0000_facebook.png");
    width:64px;
    height:64px;  
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Then why didn't you post that in the first place? Your solution was faulty at first.

Comment: I have added code then why need to create js fiddle link, have you try this before..?

Comment: I didn't have to. You had to! If you post an answer to a question, it's your responsibility to ensure that it's correct.

Comment: If you have no idea about it's working or not then how you can give downvote to someone, let it be if you think it's not working then you are right and I am wrong.

Comment: Maybe you don't realise, but the edit history of posts is always visible. So everybody can see that you posted a non-working answer at first, then edited it after I said it didn't work, and then commented "yes it will".

Comment: Yeah I have edited that post, I have added display properties only, if you think I have done something wrong then apologize.

Answer (score 0):

I want to replace this line and show a custom image.

```html
<i class="fa-solid fa-graduation-cap fa-lg">
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33260684)